I cant display image button in Renpy game engine
I'm creating an inventory system for my game, and I'm trying to place an image button for each item in the inventory, but it's giving an error and I can't figure out the solution. The relevant screenshots are below, could you please help?
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
I'm creating an inventory system for my game, and I'm trying to place an image button for each item in the inventory

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
